# Water leak behind shower joint

Tags: shower, leak

I need some quick help here. I think it should be fairly easy but want to check before tackle it. In my shower there is separate valve for handheld shower like in the pictures. Whenever I use it I would notice a small stream of water come out behind the “knob”, not on the shower line. The stream come down along the tile wall. I am guessing there is a small leak in the pipe screw and just need a fresh teflon. But I am not familiar with this type yet. Do I just scrape of the caulk and turn the whole knob? This seem to me the knob is actually the joint and it is leaking at the joint as behind the wall seem fine.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just like faucets these handhelds have a few variations on how you dismantle them. Since the water is leaking down the wall and not from the top of the hose it's important that you stop using it to prevent possible water damage inside the wall.

First, disconnect the hose from the wall mount so it can be removed. Although there might be other methods, there are only two ways that I've seen to remove the wall mount - either a set screw and/or by turning it counter-clockwise. Usually it's a set screw located under the wall mount. Once the set screw is loose, grip the wall mount, turn it counter-clockwise - it should unscrew.

If it's stubborn spray some WD40 between the wall and the mount.

I know you think it only needs some new teflon tape but there is a reasonable chance that the wall mount has simply cracked over time. You may need a replacement.

Comment: Might slide on to a shaft with an o-ring and then set screw holds it in place. A photo of the bottom might show a set screw.